# Haskell -- sort list with impure function

Tags: sorting, haskell, io

How can I sort list with IO Compare function?

```
sortWith :: [String] -> (String -> String -> IO Ordering) -> IO [String]
```

Sortby expects `(a->a->Ordering)` and I don't know, how to deal with it. I am too lazy to implement quick sort myself.

Comment: What does the `Bool` mean? `sortBy` has type `(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`, which uses a function that returns an `Ordering`, not a `Bool`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no simple way. If it was possible to lift

```
sortBy :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

to

```
sortByM :: (Ord a, Monad m) => (a -> a -> m Ordering) -> [a] -> m [a]
```

you could see the order of comparisons in implementation of `sortBy`, violating referential transparency.

In general, it's easy to go from `xxxM` to `xxx` but not conversely.

Possible options:

- Implement a monadic sorting method
- Use the [monadlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monadlist) library, which contains insertion sort (as in dflemstr's answer)
- Use `unsafePerformIO` as a hack
- Switch to sorting by key and use the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

  ```
  sortOnM :: (Monad m, Ord k) => (a -> m k) -> [a] -> m [a]
  sortOnM f xs = liftM (map fst . sortBy (comparing snd)) $
                   mapM (\x -> liftM (x,) (f x)) xs
  ```

Comment: can you elaborate more on why does `sortByM` violate referential transparency?

Comment: `sortByM` does not violate it. A potential function lifting `sortBy` to `sortByM` does. Two sorting functions `sortBy1, sortBy2 :: Ord a => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]` should be fully interchangeable, even if they perform comparisons in different order. If you let `f i j = print (i,j) >> return (compare i j)` then `lift sortBy1 f` might print a different sequence from `lift sortBy2 f`.

Answer (score 3):

The `sortBy` function uses merge sort as the algorithm in GHC, but the Haskell 98 Report dictates that insertion sort should be used.

For simplicity, because I don't have a compiler so I cannot test my code, I will implement insertion sort here:

```
import Data.Foldable (foldrM)

insertByM :: (a -> a -> IO Ordering) -> a -> [a] -> IO [a]
insertByM _   x [] = return [x]
insertByM cmp x ys@(y:ys') = do
  p <- cmp x y
  case p of
    GT -> do
      rest <- insertByM cmp x ys'
      return $ y : rest
    _ -> return $ x : ys

sortByM :: (a -> a -> IO Ordering) -> [a] -> IO [a]
sortByM cmp = foldrM (insertByM cmp) []
```

As I said, I haven't tested this code, but it could/should work.

Comment: In Haskell Report 2010 it no longer dictate that insertion sort should be used. It only requires a [stable sort algorithm](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-24900020.9.3) to be used. And GHC is using [merge sort](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#sortBy).

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I've done this one before! Merge sort with monadic comparator:

```
type MComparator m a = a -> a -> m Ordering

sortByM :: (Monad m, Functor m) => MComparator m a -> [a] -> m [a]
sortByM cmp []  = return []
sortByM cmp [x] = return [x]
sortByM cmp xs = do
  let (ys, zs) = partition xs
  ys' <- sortByM cmp ys
  zs' <- sortByM cmp zs
  merge ys' zs'
  where merge [] bs = return bs
        merge as [] = return as
        merge (a:as) (b:bs) = do
          comparison <- cmp a b
          case comparison of
            LT -> (a:) <$> merge as (b:bs)
            _  -> (b:) <$> merge (a:as) bs
        partition xs = splitAt (length xs `quot` 2) xs
```

From my blog post: http://unknownparallel.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/using-monadic-effects-to-reverse-a-merge-sort/

Answer (score -3):

Was it Larry Wall who said that laziness is one of the 3 great virtues of a programmer?

It seems you want to transform a function of type (a -> a -> b) into a function of type (a -> a -> c b).   Let's plug that into [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+b%29).  Now, if you know that IO is a Monad, you'll see about the 10th match down in liftM2.  Check the type of (liftM2 sortBy), is that what you want?

Comment: This is not the right answer. You should note that the comparison function (the second argument) also is in the IO monad.